# efficient Unix script to base64 decode a file with encrypted data

Tags: linux, unix, base64

The file sample below need to decode the third column and output as fourth column

```
883122374206 883122002074206 UzJocGUUh4c=
883122406445 883122002106445 U5dkVjlVWIc=
883122533096 883122002233096 U0dwcGORRxA=
883122624312 883122002324312 U5OJkFQ1NIc=
883122759484 883122002459484 U4NmgHUwV4c=
883122763589 883122002463589 U4WTAYBQmYc=
883122981968 883122002478427 UyY3QDAAFoI=
883122936510 883122002636510 U4kggBFncxA=
883122326985 883122002666363 U1lwcHcyBBA=
883122330017 883122002668313 U3JlEVRBiIc=
883122339137 883122002673700 UwUiESBIAYc=
883122438696 883122002733023 U1MJgGJgg4c=
883122242176 883122002875188 U4Q3IBFBB0U=
883122230176 883122002883257 U2GUAXdZaIc=
883122532560 883122002232560 U4kVkFBzVhA=
```

output like

```
883122374206 883122002074206 UzJocGUUh4c=
883122406445 883122002106445 U5dkVjlVWIc=
883122533096 883122002233096 U0dwcGORRxA=
883122624312 883122002324312 U5OJkFQ1NIc=
883122759484 883122002459484 U4NmgHUwV4c=
883122763589 883122002463589 U4WTAYBQmYc=
883122981968 883122002478427 UyY3QDAAFoI=
883122936510 883122002636510 U4kggBFncxA=
883122326985 883122002666363 U1lwcHcyBBA=
883122330017 883122002668313 U3JlEVRBiIc=
883122339137 883122002673700 UwUiESBIAYc=
883122438696 883122002733023 U1MJgGJgg4c=
883122242176 883122002875188 U4Q3IBFBB0U=
883122230176 883122002883257 U2GUAXdZaIc=
883122532560 883122002232560 U4kVkFBzVhA=
```

when decoding one item I use script

```
echo "U2GUAXdZaIc=" | base64 --decode | hexdump -v -e '/1 "%x"' | dd conv=swab status=none;echo
```

when I decode only column3 using `base64 -d` below I get one line output file, how can I get line by line output ?

```
cat DS10_export41.ldif | base64 --decode | hexdump -v -e '/1 "%x"' | dd conv=swab status=none oflag=sync of=DS10_export42.ldif
```

Comment: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001

Comment: `output like` I see no difference between output and input.

Comment: sorry my mistake, here is the output I mean sample: 
883122406445 883122002106445 U5dkVjlVWIc= 3579466593558578
883122533096 883122002233096 U0dwcGORRxA= 3574070736197401
883122624312 883122002324312 U5OJkFQ1NIc= 3539980945534378
883122759484 883122002459484 U4NmgHUwV4c= 3538660857037578